# How to normalize a list from a json file using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample file like this

sample.json

```
{
   "school":[
      {
         "testId":123,
         "testName":"test1",
         "Teachers":[
            {
               "Tid":111,
               "Tname":"aaa"
            },
            {
               "Tid":222,
               "Tname":"bbb"
            },
            {
               "Tid":333,
               "Tname":"ccc"
            },
            {
               "Tid":444,
               "Tname":"ddd"
            }
         ],
         "location":"India"
      }
   ]
}
```

i need to normalize the Teachers list from this file, my code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('sample.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='school', max_level=1)
df.to_csv("out.csv",index=False)
```

output:
[image]

I need to get an output like this:

[image]

is it possible to get this output without passing the keywords "Tid" and "Tname"?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what record_path does, check the counties example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for how it's actually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, use a list in `record_path`:

```
pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['school', 'Teachers'])
```

Or subset the dictionary:

```
pd.json_normalize(data['school'], record_path='Teachers', max_level=1)
```

Output:

```
   Tid Tname
0  111   aaa
1  222   bbb
2  333   ccc
3  444   ddd
```

With helper columns:

```
pd.json_normalize(data['school'], record_path='Teachers',
                  meta=['testId', 'testName', 'location'], max_level=1)
```

Output:

```
   Tid Tname testId testName location
0  111   aaa    123    test1    India
1  222   bbb    123    test1    India
2  333   ccc    123    test1    India
3  444   ddd    123    test1    India
```

Comment: Using school as part of the record_path is almost certainly not what's desired. Just pass `data["school"]` instead

Comment: @SweetSheep it's hard to generalize, given OP's example this should do the trick, but yes `pd.json_normalize(data['school'], record_path='Teachers', max_level=1)` is doing the same here

Comment: what do I need to do if I want to keep the other columns as well? like, `testId,testName,Tid,Tname,location` ?

Comment: Then `pd.json_normalize(data['school'], record_path='Teachers', meta=['testId', 'testName', 'location'], max_level=1)`